How to use tools with LLMs?
I am using the stream interface of completions, e.g.
const completion = await client.chat.completions.create({
  messages,
  model: '...',
  stream: true,
  stream_options: {
    include_usage: true,
  },
   tool_choice: {
    type: 'function',
    function: {
      name: 'searchWeb',
    },
  },
  tools: [searchWeb],
  user: chatSession.userAccount.uid,
});

I want to force this LLM to use webSearch tool.
This is how I am handling the response:
type ToolCall = {
  function?: {
    arguments?: string;
    name?: string;
  };
  id?: string;
  index: number;
  type?: 'function';
};

const toolCalls: Record<string, ToolCall> = {};

for await (const chunk of completion) {
  const [choice] = chunk.choices;

  if (typeof choice.delta.content === 'string') {
    send({
      content,
      status: 'started',
    });
  }

  if (choice.delta?.tool_calls) {
    for (const toolCall of choice.delta.tool_calls) {
      if (!toolCalls[toolCall.index]) {
        toolCalls[toolCall.index] = toolCall;
      }

      const localToolCall = toolCalls[toolCall.index];

      if (
        typeof toolCall.function?.arguments === 'string' &&
        typeof localToolCall?.function?.arguments === 'string'
      ) {
        localToolCall.function.arguments += toolCall.function.arguments;
      }
    }
  }

  if (choice.finish_reason === 'function_call') {
    // This never happens ???
  }


  if (choice.finish_reason === 'stop') {
    const toolEntries = Object.entries(toolCalls);

    if (toolEntries.length > 0) {
      for (const [, toolCall] of toolEntries) {
        const matchingTool = toolPlan?.tools.find((tool) => {
          return tool.function.name === toolCall.function?.name;
        });

        if (!matchingTool) {
          throw new UnexpectedStateError('Unexpected tool call', {
            toolCall,
          });
        }

        if (!toolCall.function?.arguments) {
          throw new UnexpectedStateError('Expected tool call arguments', {
            toolCall,
          });
        }

        const args = parseJson(toolCall.function?.arguments);

        console.log('args', toolCall, args, matchingTool);

        // What now ???
      }
    }
  }
}

This gets me to the point where I have LLM describe what function should be invoked – but what's next? am I supposed to restart the entire completion and add to messages assistant messages with tool_calls and the corresponding tool responses?, e.g.,
messages [
  {
    content: 'whats the best framework for testing in nodejs?',
    role: 'user'
  },
  {
    content: null,
    role: 'assistant',
    tool_calls: [
      {
        function: {
          arguments: '{"query":"best node.js test framework"}',
          name: 'searchWeb'
        },
        id: 'call_cLiEnGf4H9zB4BMz6TQMQmwA',
        type: 'function'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    content: '{"answer":"Vitest is the best framework for testing Node.js code."}',
    role: 'tool',
    tool_call_id: 'call_cLiEnGf4H9zB4BMz6TQMQmwA'
  }
]

If yes, then how can I provide instructions about the formatting of the final response?

Yes, you need to run multiple OpenAI queries:

Query OpenAI for function and function parameters
Execute webSearch function
Query OpenAI using entirely new prompt that includes results from webSearch and formatting instructions. If you want e.g. a JSON response include an example of the JSON and activate the JSON-mode


Can you show an example of what the second round-trip would look like?
